How should I configure my docker-compose file so that i can persist my keycloak realm?
I'm trying to secure my springboot application with keycloak but after a certain period keycloak resests and deletes the realm that i created so I have to create it again. I have patially imported my realm and everytime I recreate it using the JSON file i downloaded but I want to persist it in my docker-compose.yml file.
This is what i already added to the file, is there something else I should do?
KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
KC_METRICS_ENABLED: 'true'
KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: 'true'
KC_IMPORT_DIR: /opt/keycloak/data/import  # Adjust if your data directory is different
command: start-dev
ports:
  - '8080:8080'
healthcheck:
  test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8080;echo -e \"GET /health/ready HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: http://localhost\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n\" >&3;grep \"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\" <&3" ]
  interval: 5s
  timeout: 5s
  retries: 3
depends_on:
  postgres:
    condition: service_healthy
# New volume to store realm data
volumes:
  - realm_data:/opt/keycloak/data/import  # Adjust mount point if needed

I tried adding this code to my docker-compose file
KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
KC_METRICS_ENABLED: 'true'
KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: 'true'
KC_IMPORT_DIR: /opt/keycloak/data/import  # Adjust if your data directory is different
command: start-dev
ports:
  - '8080:8080'
healthcheck:
  test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8080;echo -e \"GET /health/ready HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: http://localhost\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n\" >&3;grep \"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\" <&3" ]
  interval: 5s
  timeout: 5s
  retries: 3
depends_on:
  postgres:
    condition: service_healthy
# New volume to store realm data
volumes:
  - realm_data:/opt/keycloak/data/import  # Adjust mount point if needed

